# How to implement a Slim v2 hook as middleware in Slim v3

Tags: php, oop, slim, middleware, slim-3

In Slim Framework v2 I use simple authentication function as a hook to check if a route needs login.

This is authentication code:

```
$authenticate = function ( $app ) {
    return function () use ( $app ) {
        if ( !isset( $_SESSION['userid'] ) ) {
            $_SESSION['urlRedirect'] = $app->request()->getPathInfo();
            $app->flash('danger', 'You need to login');
            $app->redirect('/login');
        }
    };
};
```

this is how I use in Slim v2:

```
$app->get("/user/change-password", $authenticate($app), function () use ( $app ) {

 $userStuff->changePassowrd($_SESSION['userid'], $newPassword, $oldPassword);

});
```

I can implement this to Slim v3 without a problem but I can't seem to understand how I supposed to do this with middleware(to learn and use the functionally)

I have tried this: this is my middleware class;

```
<?php
namespace entity;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

class Auth
{
    /**
     * Example middleware invokable class
     *
     * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request  PSR7 request
     * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface      $response PSR7 response
     * @param  callable                                 $next     Next middleware
     *
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
     */
     public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
     {
       if ($this->authenticate()) {
        $response = $next($request, $response);
      } else {
        echo 'You need to login';
      }
      return $response;
     }

     public function authenticate() {
       if ( !isset( $_SESSION['userid'] ) ) {
          return true;
       }
       return false;
     }
}

?>
```

Registered it:

```
$app->add( new entity\Auth() );
```

and I don't know how to use this on a route as I did in Slim v2, where do I add this in the route to check if that route needs an authentication?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is actually excluding a route for the `Auth` middleware.
You **do want** that check for all other routes but not for `changePassword`.

In your `__invoke` you need to [get the current route](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/retrieving-current-route.html) and only do `authenticate` if the route is not `changePassword` (if that's the name of your route).

```
public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
{
    $route = $request->getAttribute('route');
    if (in_array($route->getName(), ['changePassword']) || $this->authenticate()) {
        $response = $next($request, $response);
    } else {
        echo 'You need to login';
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the basic example is next

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

class Auth {
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next) {
        if ($this->authenticate()) {
            $response = $next($request, $response);
        } else {
            echo 'You need to login';
        }
        return $response;
    }

    public function authenticate() {
        if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->get('/open', function($request, $response, $args){
    echo 'HAPPINESS FOR EVERYBODY, FREE, AND LET NO ONE BE LEFT BEHIND!';
});

$app->get('/closed', function($request, $response, $args){
    echo 'You are authenticated!';
})->add(new Auth());

$app->get('/login', function($request, $response, $args){
    $_SESSION['userid'] = 1;
});

$app->run();
```

I think there was a mistake in as `authenticate` function as `!isset` means there is no `$_SESSION['userid']` and probably user is not logged in and your function tells that he is logged.

But anyway you can add middleware to single route or group of routes with `add()` method.